# Monitor lightbox project – does this exist yet?

Tags: python, hdmi, script, composite-video

I have a second monitor next to my iMac. What I’d like to do is set up a Pi that simply outputs solid colour to the monitor over HDMI or composite (it has both), thus allowing me to use it as a video conferencing light panel.

As a starting point, I'd just preset the colour and have it simple show that on startup. The next step would be controlling it with potentiometers – three pots for R/G/B, or H/S/L or four for RGB+Brightness. Maybe colour temp+brightness and only two pots? A web interface might suit my prior coding experience better but none of my Pis have WLAN built in and it seems like over-complication. I want this to be a simple appliance.

The question: is there anything like this already? Do you know of a resource that would be a good starting point?

I’ve only used my Pis with general purpose linux distros or media player OSs before. I’m curious to see what can be done with minimal python code.

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: start with serving a local web page that has solid color background ... use encoders for controls ...  mouse would also work ... i think that a Raspberry Pi does not have analog input for the potentiometers